Neural Network Hyperparameter tuning and variable importance with burlee
I am new to neural networks.  I was wondering how to do a few things using the burlee package.  One, I am trying to figure out how to tune the hyperparamters (i.e., number of hidden layers and the penalty).  Is this done using a grid and tune_grid?  With neural networks, I am a bit fuzzy on how to do this.  Anyone one how is this done?  Second, I am trying to figure out how to get the variable importance metrics from brulee.  Does anyone know how this is done?  Again, I am new to neural networks.  Any assistance is greatly appreciated.  I am experimenting with the following code:
library(tidymodels)
library(brulee)

data("parabolic")

set.seed(1)
parabolic_split <- initial_split(parabolic)
parabolic_tr <- training(parabolic_split)
parabolic_te <- testing(parabolic_split)

grid_hidden_units <- tribble(
  ~hidden_units,
  c(8, 8),
  c(8, 8, 8),
  c(16, 16),
  c(16, 16, 16),
)

grid_penalty <- tibble(penalty = c(0.01, 0.02))


set.seed(2)
cls_fit <- brulee_mlp(
  class ~ ., data = parabolic_tr, 
  ## two layers with 5 hidden units each:
  hidden_units = c(5, 5),
  epochs = 50L, learn_rate = 0.1, batch_size = 2^8
)

predict(cls_fit, grid, type = "prob") %>%
  bind_cols(grid) %>%
  ggplot(aes(X1, X2)) +
  geom_contour(aes(z = .pred_Class1), breaks = 1/2, col = "black") +
  geom_point(data = parabolic_te, aes(col = class))

#variable importance
vip_plot <- vip(extract_fit_parsnip(cls_fit)) + 
  theme(text = element_text(size=20)) 

Thank you
